# Propagation of watermark in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have some doubts regarding the propagation of watermark in Flink application. I've seen in the documentation and in some posts that Flink chooses the lowest watermark to propagate through the operators. I don't understand in some cases how that works. I have a small use case to easily understand my question.

I'm using Flink 1.15.2. I have two sources:

```
First message:

Source One -----> 10
                       one.union(two) ----> watermark propagated is it 9?
Source two -----> 9

Second message:

Source One -----> 12
                       one.union(two) ----> watermark propagated is it 11 or 9?
Source two -----> 11

Third message (Let's assume that Source two has a very small delay)

Source One -----> 15
                       one.union(two) ----> watermark propagated is it 13 or other value?
Source two --> 13
```

I will appreciate some help to understand that point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I take it that the numbers represent timestamps in messages. Or are they watermarks? What is the watermark strategy?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdhwpUAjqaI covers this in some detail.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your answer. In this example i'm using a custom punctuated watermark strategy, so i'm producing a watermark by each event (take the timestamp from the event and produce the watermark). In the example the value can be the generated watermark.

Answer (score 0):

Given that in this example, watermarks are being produced for every event, and with no out-of-orderness, then the watermarks being propagated will be 9, 11, and 13.

Comment: Thanks David. Let's assume a fourth message in my example.

 
Source One -----> 6  Source two -----> 7  one.union(two)

In this case, since the watermark is less (6) than what we have in the operators (13),  will it propagate or will it be ignored because it is smaller? Basically i'm asking if the watermark 13 after the unions is going to be replace by 6.

Thanks

Comment: The watermark can never go backwards. The events with timestamps of 6 and 7 will be propagated, but the watermark will remain unchanged at 13.